# Editing a pdf page by page

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm trying to make unique edits to individual pages in a pre-existing pdf. However, the edits remain the same.

I've tried using FPDF (wasn't sure of how to edit a pre-existing pdf with this) and then am now trying PYPDF2 with reportlab.

```
#
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import io
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter

def WriteOnPdf (targetpdf, pageTopicsDict):
    packet = io.BytesIO()
    # Create a new PDF with Reportlab
    can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
    can.setFont('Helvetica', 13)
    can.drawString(5, 730, pageTopicsDict[0])
    can.save()

    # Move to the beginning of the StringIO buffer
    packet.seek(0)
    new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
    # Read your existing PDF
    existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open(targetpdf, "rb"))
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    # Add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page

    for i in range(existing_pdf.numPages):
        print(i, pageTopicsDict[i])
        can.drawString(5, 730, pageTopicsDict[i])
        page = existing_pdf.getPage(i)
        page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))# index out of range if not set to 0.
        output.addPage(page)    

    # Finally, write "output" to a real file
    outputStream = open("destination.pdf", "wb")
    output.write(outputStream)
    outputStream.close()

dummyDict = {0: "abc", 1: "de, fg", 2: "hijklmn"}
WriteOnPdf ("test.pdf", dummyDict)
```

Expected: pdf with "abc" on top left hand corner of page 0, "de, fg" on page 1, "hijklmn" on page 2...
Actual: all pages have "abc"

Answer (score 0):

Solved; initialized the packet and relevant variables in the for loop instead of outside.